# Is it a good idea to buy the Canon 5d mkii body only & buy the lenses separately?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, video

'm a first time buyer of a Canon camera and I'm getting a 5D today. I'm using it for short films and music videos, etc.  I have an EF 18-55mm f/3.5-5.6 and an EF 70-300mm f/4-5.6 lens. So, would it be a good idea to just buy the 5dmkii body only... or does the kit come with other stuff when you the get kit? (I also want to get a 50mm 1.8 or 1.4 lens.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should I buy a kit, or body + lens separately?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/790/should-i-buy-a-kit-or-body-lens-separately)

Comment: I suggested the duplicate, but it is worth noting that the particularly high quality of the lens offered with the 5D mkII as a kit may make this a special case.

Comment: @mattdm the answers in that question cover the fact that there is L series glass in the 5D and 1D kits.

Comment: @cabbey: well then. :)

Comment: The 18-55 is an EF-S lens which fits the Canon APS-C sensor bodies, it will therefore not fit on you 5D.

Answer (score 7):

The Canon 5D Mk II has two options, the camera body by itself or the camera body and the [Canon 24-105mm f/4L IS USM AF Lens](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/583987-REG/Canon_2764B004_EOS_5D_Mark_II.html). Some stores such as Adorama also package additional items with the camera such as memory cards, batteries, bags, cleaning tools, or a grip. These are not kits put together by Canon, they are just [bundling additional items](http://www.adorama.com/searchsite/default.aspx?searchinfo=ICA5DM2&utm_source=rflaid021866&utm_medium=Affiliate&utm_campaign=Search&utm_term=ICA5DM2) along with the Camera at one price point.

While considering your current lens lineup, the kit lens is a huge step up in terms of quality. The 24-105mm lens is a professional lens, and as such has many advanced features that your current lenses do not offer. Another thing to consider is that you save about $300 when you purchase this lens as part of the kit and not separately. That alone makes it a great option for many. Unlike many kit lenses, the 24-105mm is actually a very competitive option and well worth considering.

**Overall, I think the 5D kit is a great option for your particular case. The Adorama "kits" are not really necessary and probably include knock off brand's that you don't need.**

Answer (score 4):

Unless I'm mistaken, the 18-55 is an EF-S lens, not EF, and won't mount on the full-frame 5D.  Per Canon's lens lineup page, http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/consumer/products/cameras/ef_lens_lineup, the 70-300 is an EF lens and will mount on the 5D.

I've never bought a body new, but my impression is that a kit is just a lens, usually at a small discount, along with the body; if you are going to buy the lens anyway you might as well get them together.  It sounds like you might need a lens "similar" to the 18-55, and the 24-105 that @dpollitt mentioned would do the trick; the 24-70 might also be worth considering.

Also, did you consider getting a 7D (crop-sensor) body instead?  The 18-55 (not that it's a terribly expensive lens) would work with that.  It would be a step down in image quality from the 5D, though.

Answer (score 0):

The 5D MkII has a lot of possibilities when purchasing: you can go for the body only, standard kit or many sellers provide their own bundle deals with very good lenses. The 18-55 is an EF-S lens so will not mount on the 5D because the 5D is a full frame sensor and EF-S lenses only work with crop sensor bodies. So if you need a lens with it I would recommend you go for a kit with L glass, or the last option because a camera of this quality really requires good glass.

As you're going for a 5D MkII I'm going to guess that limited budget is not a prime factor. Given this I would recommend going for a bundle offer with a Canon L series lens, something like a 24-70 f/2.8L which is a very good, if expensive, all-around lens whose quality matches the camera body and is supplied as a bundle with this body by some sellers. On a full frame body like the 5D this will be roughly equivalent to the 18-55 you have on a crop sensor body.

If you want to use the 18-55 you have you would need to consider a crop sensor body like a 7D which is a fine body having the same build quality as the 5D MkII but more up-to-date features and especially better video capabilities than the 5D MKII.  If you're going to be doing a lot of video with this I would recommend a battery grip as video drains the battery quite quickly on these cameras.

Comment: Please do not choose cameras based on which ones support the 18-55. It's just not worth it if you are willing to spend more money.

Answer (score 0):

Among your existing lenses, the 18-55mm is an EF-S (for APS-C Sensors only) lens and will not mount on the 5D Mark II body. The 70-300mm will mount but its a longer lens than your interests (short films/music videos) will need. I'd suggest you get the 24-105mm f/4.0 kit lens. If money isn't a problem, get the 24-70mm f/2.8 instead, it will complement your 70-300mm lens better. Also getting a 50mm f/1.4 or f/1.8 is a good idea for doing video works.

Answer (score 0):

Get the 24-105L, it's a superb walkaround lens and will compliment the full frame 5d.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of buying body-only.