# Where can I find good example pictures for the influence of focal length on image composition

Tags: portrait, shooting-technique, art

In [this answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/48941/25699), Stan argues that having the choice between many focal lenghts in a large range is essential for studio photography, making a zoom lens a good choice.

This was surprising to me  as a beginner, since I'd assumed that "zooming with your legs" would be completely sufficient in a limited space. In the same vein, It's always sounded strange to me when focal lengths of 100mm or more are called "portrait lenses" when a portrait is supposed to show a person the way another human interacting with them would see them - and isn't that what a normal 50mm focal length does?

Now I do know that the focal length influences not just the angle of view but also the way objects appear relative to each other, but I guess I've never really considered it relevant except in extreme cases.

The [dolly zoom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dolly_zoom) demonstrates pretty clearly the technical effect, but are there example pictures or maybe even a tutorial that shows it in terms of artistic image composition?

Comment: Based on history, asking for _where you can find_ examples gets you a few short responses and a few links, but nothing great or lasting. It's better to ask for answers _here_.

Comment: We do have [Which focal-length lens is usually used for portrait photography, and why?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/916/1943) about portrait lenses in specific.

Comment: And [How can a telephoto lens take great landscape photos?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/21812/1943) covers much of the topic for landscape.

Comment: But, we don't have a broad general question about traditional focal lengths 
and their typical use cases (and strengths and weaknesses for different
applications). I don't think it would be bad at all to turn this question into that.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few places that you can do that.

My preferred, but not specifically for that is flickr.com

You can search for all type of photography, and all of the photos have meta data information. When I started I used that a lot. Another thing that you can do is also go to a specific photographers website. Someone that you like and look at their meta data on the photos they have on the website.

I did this recently for a photo I thought was interesting and wanted to know what the aperture/shutter speed were.

you should keep in mind that its not always possible to get metadata as some people don't upload that information into their jpgs etc.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

How about this [long, lost blog article](http://photo.blogoverflow.com/2012/05/portrait-perspective/)?  It shows a variety of focal lengths :)

Comment: Oooh, ooh: http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4264/should-we-migrate-posts-from-the-blog-to-be-self-answered-questions

Comment: And by "oooh, ooh", I mean you should post that as an answer, either here or (I think better) to [the one on portrait focal lengths](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/916/1943)

Comment: Here also a relevant, cat friendly explanation: http://petapixel.com/2013/01/11/how-focal-length-affects-your-subjects-apparent-weight-as-seen-with-a-cat/