# Is Canon 60D still a decent camera?

Tags: canon, dslr

I have a Canon 60D, bought it back in 2013. Use it quite a while, but in past two-three years, I lost interest in photography. I will be going on a long trip this summer and would like to take a decent camera with me. Is Canon 60D still a decent one or I will be missing on features and upgrades comparing to the latest versions?

In terms of lenses I own Tamron 24-70 2.8 And Canon 100 2.8 Macro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have a Canon 60D, bought it back in 2013. Use it quite a while, but in past two-three years, I lost interest in photography. I will be going on a long trip this summer and would like to take a decent camera with me. Is Canon 60D still a decent one ...

It's a decent camera, even today. If you've 'lost interest' spending money is something you have to decide for yourself.

Take the camera and your lenses, possibly see if somewhere will rent a lens for a vacation or use the Internet to research somewhere to rent lenses at your destination (and read their **Fine Print**).

Bring your phone, a backup camera (and portable telephone) is handy while traveling.

> ... or I will be missing on features and upgrades comparing to the latest versions?

Yes, you're missing a bit. You can find out what by using 'Online Comparison Tools':

- [Camera Decision - Canon EOS 80D vs. Canon EOS 60D](http://cameradecision.com/compare/Canon-EOS-80D-vs-Canon-EOS-60D)
- [Imaging Resource - Canon EOS 60D vs. Canon EOS 80D](https://www.imaging-resource.com/cameras/canon/60d/vs/canon/80d/)
- [SnapSort - Canon EOS 60D vs. Canon EOS 80D](http://snapsort.com/compare/Canon-EOS-80D-vs-Canon_EOS_60D)

Once you determine what you're *missing* (not an awful lot) you can use the link suggested by @scottbb [When should I upgrade my camera body?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/71199/when-should-i-upgrade-my-camera-body) to decide if it's "worth it" - I [opine](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/opine) no.

Since you have so few lenses another choice is to get out of Canon's two digit lineup and look elsewhere. If saving size and weight is your primary consideration then mirrorless is another option.

- [Camera Decision - Canon M5 (Semi-Pro Mirrorless) vs Canon 60D (Semi-Pro DSLR)](http://cameradecision.com/compare/Canon-EOS-M5-vs-Canon-EOS-60D)

They make some compact mirrorless cameras like the [M100](http://cameradecision.com/compare/Canon-EOS-M100-vs-Canon-EOS-60D), you should examine **why** you became disinterested and seek to fix that - without spending a lot of money.

> In terms of lenses I own Tamron 24-70 2.8 And Canon 100 2.8 Macro.

See prior advice about renting, if it's an expensive trip (far away) a bunch of great (and different focal length) photos makes financial sense; to record your memories and increase the value of trip.

Spending money sounds like an easy fix, the question is: will it fix the problem?

Comment: Thanks for actually answering the question, rather than making it about lens focal length choices!

Comment: The question is still basically the same: Should I upgrade just because my camera is not the latest, greatest, newest model?

Comment: @MichaelClark - Your welcome. The other question seemed more about: "I use my camera regularly, at which point should I upgrade?", and this question seemed more about "I lost interest in photography but have a reasonable camera with few lenses, now I have a need to take photos again. Am I best served by renting some lenses for the short time I intend to revisit photography or will a new camera rekindle my interest and *fix* everything?". I suggested to save his money for lens rental and the vacation, to wait longer before upgrading **unless** he knows it was the weight or something specific .

Comment: I still don't get why everyone is obsessed about renting/adding lenses. The OP doesn't indicate any dissatisfaction at all with not having angles of view outside the 24-70 on an APS-C camera. The OP just wants to know if the camera body is too out of date to be useful. Just because *some of us* would want wider/longer focal lengths available for such a trip does not make the OP's lenses out of date.

Comment: @MichaelClark - I am OK with the lenses but a longer one wouldn't hurt, that's such a minimal selection the he could have gone with non-ILC. He says that he lost interest, it certainly wasn't due to straining over which lens to compose the shot with. My answer suggests that he satisfies himself that the camera body is recent enough. He should examine **why** he lost interest and direct his money in that direction. If it was too much fiddling then P&S, if trouble getting the shot a wider and longer lens is missing. If it's the weight there are lighter options. He must look within. Gear / Guy?

Comment: But see, that is just the difference between you and I and anyone else. For a vacation trip I'd feel much more limited by having nothing wider than 24mm on an APS-C camera (40mm on FF) than not having anything beyond 70mm (110mm on a FF).

Comment: May I suggest submitting this same answer to the question this one was marked as a duplicate? I've done the same on occasion and included an introductory note that the answer was originally written for "Name of the other question" with a link embedded to the closed/duplicate question (or added the same type of note when the questions were merged by a mod). Something like [this one](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/83269/15871) or [this one](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/40136/15871)

Comment: One of @MichaelClark comments:  "I still don't get why **everyone** is obsessed about ...", and the **next** comment: "But see, that is just the difference between you and I and **anyone else**.  ..." -- So ... Anyone except everyone ...

Comment: OK. "... *most* everyone (who answered the question - which was asked by *someone* in particular who does not seem at all concerned with missing focal lengths/angles of view) is obsessed. And "... you and I and *someone* else..."

Answer (score 9):

It's as good a camera now as it was then. Unless you understand what about the 60D is limiting your photography, then the right option is not to spend money. You'll almost certainly get more value out of either a wide angle or telephoto lens - you can pick up either the EF-S 10-18 or EF-S 55-250 for a *lot* less than a new body (or both for still a lot less than an 80D), and both will give you whole new possibilities when travelling, as opposed to the incremental improvement you get from a new body.

Comment: Or the  18-135 and maybe a 50mm 1.8 - good travel lenses IMO.

Comment: I don't read the question as being mostly about lens selection, which is what most of this answer is about. The question is "Is the Canon 60D still a decent camera?"

Answer (score 0):

The 60D is still a great, capable camera. My Nikon D5000 that I use as an extra body is still great, despite it being from 2009. As others have said, you will definitely benefit from new lenses, though. The problem is that if your vacation is long and you will be walking/hiking a lot, carrying around a big heavy DSLR can (and most likely will) be tiring. You can always rent out a nice mirrorless camera (or even buy one) for hiking and use the 60D for everything else. Also, one thing to keep in mind is that the camera is nothing, the person behind the camera is everything!

Edit: to talk more about cameras and less about lenses.

Comment: Welcome to photography@SE! Reading this answer leaves one with the impression that lenses become outdated faster than cameras! Nothing could be further from the truth. The user should already be aware of the limitations of the angles of view with their current lenses that they've owned for five years. The question was not "Do I need wider angle lenses?" The question was about whether the camera body is outdated.

Comment: ugh, and now we want to buy a mirrorless for what? Saving a little weight?