# whats with the nikor lens naming using the letters D + G?

Tags: lens, nikon

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do all those cryptic number and letter codes in a lens name mean?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/496/what-do-all-those-cryptic-number-and-letter-codes-in-a-lens-name-mean)

## Nikon 50mm f/1.8D

## Nikon 35mm f/1.8G

what does the D and G distinction mean on these lenses and why does it matter?

Comment: Duplicate: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/496/what-does-all-those-parts-in-a-lens-name-mean

Comment: This is definitely a duplicate of the question matt noted. I'm closing as a duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

G means "gelded" which means there is no aperture ring and so the aperture can only be adjusted on the camera itself.  D means "distance information" and helps the camera to know what it is focusing on based on distance.

http://www.ehow.com/about_5385361_nikon-vs-lenses.html

Comment: I *highly* doubt that Nikon chose to label their lenses with a pejorative term like that. More likely that's an after-the-fact joke explanation made by a clever but unhappy customer.

Comment: In this context the G(elded) lens is also a D. See http://www.kenrockwell.com/nikon/nikortek.htm#g ... Ken also explains the other limitations of G.

Comment: While I tend to agree with Matt about the naming, I do think it's an apt description for it.