# What does the "L" in the L-Series Canon lenses stand for?

Tags: lens, canon

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between Canon “L” lenses and non-L lenses?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/7061/what-is-the-difference-between-canon-l-lenses-and-non-l-lenses)

Any ideas? Just curious. Some seem to think it stands for Luxury.

Comment: See also: http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/496/21

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Some" include Canon, apparently.

Page 15 of "Lens work III", book 2, "Canon's Challenges". Quote:

'L Lenses
Where Dreams Are Crystal Clear.

The bright red line engraved on the lens barrel. And an L for "luxury."'

Lens Work is a useful title by the way, it gives a complete (if slightly dated) rundown of Canon's lens lineup and illustrates some of the thinking behind it. Canon has it available for download if you google around a bit.

Comment: I have a hard copy of that book. It is outdated, of course, but still nice to flick through now and again.  Good coffee table material :-)