# What do the AF-A, AF-C, and AF-S autofocus settings mean?

Tags: autofocus, terminology

My camera has these settings for autofocus, and I don't know what they mean. I suspect "A" is "Auto", and "C" is "continuous", but I have no idea what "S" is.

Comment: What is the make and model of your camera?

Comment: @Matt: It's a Nikon D7000 but I believe I have seen similar markings on a friend's Canon before.

Comment: See also: http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/496/21

Comment: @Rowland: No, I'm not talking about AF-S lenses, I'm talking about the autofocus mode. (It's unfortunate the names overlap)

Comment: It's often best to include enough information in the question to make it unambiguous -- I see Craig has now edited it to include that; it would also be good in the future to give an indication as to what your camera is; many of the abbreviations used are specific to a particular manufacturer (for example, @vlad259 tries to cover both options)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[This](http://www.slrphotographyguide.com/camera/nikon-digital-slr/focus-modes.shtml) link explains it well. Paraphrasing the article:

> - AF-C (AF-continuous or servo mode) is used for photographing moving
>     subjects.
> - AF-S means single shot and is used for subject that is
>     stationary.
> - AF-A is where the camera decides whether the subject is
>     moving or not and tries to alternate between the servo and single shot
>     mode accordingly.

Answer (score 10):

There is another important difference between AF-S and AF-C.  With AF-S, you cannot take a shot without focus being locked (green light being on).  With AF-C you will take a shot anytime the shutter release is pressed.  So with AF-C, while it will attempt to track focus on a moving subject, you can take shots at any time whether or not the AF has focus lock.

Comment: At least on the D7000, this is configurable. The default behavior of AF-S is to wait for a lock because it is intended to shoot stationary subjects. But you can override this and force the camera to take the shot anyway by holding the AF-LOCK button (or you can change how this works completely).

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes 'Servo' - continuous autofocus and sometimes 'Single' - one shot.

Try it by focusing on a moving subject and see what it does...

Answer (score -4):

When AF-S appears on a lens:

AF-S: Autofocus Silent
Focusing is driven by a "Silent Wave" motor in the lens instead of the focus drive motor in the camera. AF-S lenses focus faster than standard AF-Nikkors and almost completely silently. AF-S lenses with a "II" designation weigh less and are generally smaller than their equivalent predecessors.

Comment: The question wasn't about AF-S in a lens's specification; it was about the AF-S autofocus setting in the camera.