# What are the different types of auto-focus motor and how do they compare?

Tags: lens, autofocus, focus-motor

What is the difference of ultrasonic motor, stepper motor, and electromagnetic drive?
Which one of these are lens-based or screwdrive?
What are the advantages of lens-based servo over screwdrive and vice versa?
Are camera body normally built to have autofocus motor or normally lens-based?

I'm looking for

1. Technological difference
2. Usage difference
3. Price and availability
4. Advancement in recent years

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does STM mean on a Canon lens?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/24109/what-does-stm-mean-on-a-canon-lens)

Comment: Sounds like questions for a research paper :)

Comment: If you are interested in recent developments perhaps you should include the development of linear electromagnetic focus motors in your question. For more about what they are (as well as a very brief survey of the history of other focusing methods) see https://www.lensrentals.com/blog/2016/04/a-look-at-electromagnetic-focusing/

Comment: See: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/74876

Comment: @PhilipKendall No, I know what stepper motor is, and I happen to have one. The thing is about the advantages, disadvantages and technical difference of the two which I don't get.

Comment: I think that the final paragraph of Matt Grum's answer to the duplicate covers all that. What specific points do you need more clarification on?

Comment: The Lensrentals link that Michael Clark provided should answer most of the questions asked by the OP.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is Nano USM and how does it compare to an STM or USM lens?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/74876/what-is-nano-usm-and-how-does-it-compare-to-an-stm-or-usm-lens)

Comment: I feel there might be demand for a comprehensive answer detailing different technologies, different manufacturers' brand names, etc. The linked questions are quite Canon-specific.

Comment: Indeed, Johannes, I should also change my question as STM, USM and such are Canon-specific. The question is a general question on every manufacturer and their implementation.

Overall it's more like asking about its history.