# Are these Nikon 16-85mm lenses actually the same?

Tags: lens, nikon, terminology

I just ordered the D7000 with three lenses, one of them was the Nikon AF 16-85 mm f/3.5-5.6 DX G AF-S ED. Now I found that they sell a package "D7000 with 16-85mm, AFS G VR" for $100 less. I can undo my order before midnight, is it the same lens? (If so I'll reorder with the package instead of the camera and lens separately.) The full name does say both AF and AF-S, but no AFS.. Sorry if this is a newbie question..

Comment: If the acronyms in the names are correct, one seems to be VR, or Vibration Reduction, where as the other is not. VR, or IS (image stabilization) as its called in Canon circles, is pretty handy, particularly for focal lengths beyond 50mm for full frame, or 35mm for APS-C. Second, you mentioned you bought a package with three lenses. Is the alternative package that is $100 less only one lens, or is it still three lenses, just with the alternative VR version of the 16-85mm?

Comment: I bought a camera and lenses separatly. It seems that I can get one of the lenses "bundled" with the camera for $100 less.

Comment: @jrista Does Nikon sell a version without VR? Couldn't find any information on their web-pages.

Comment: I thought it had to be the same because I think they only have one, but since it comes with the camera I thought maybe it is a different lens. (Because I'd expected them to advertise with VR if they could..)

Comment: I'm not a Nikon user, so I don't know if there is not a non-VR version of this lens. It was the only discrepancy I could see from the question, though, hence the mention. If there is only a VR version, then I'd go for the bundle.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[There is only one such lens](http://www.neocamera.com/lens/nikkor/af-s_dx_16-85mm_f3.5-5.6g_ed_vr) and so, yes, **they are the same**.

The full name is the **Nikkor AF-S DX 16-85mm F/3.5-5.6G ED VR** but it seems one of your vendors is omitting parts of the name. Unfortunately this is common practice and makes it extremely confusing since many lenses were built with multiple variations over the years (with and without VR, with an without focus-motor, etc).

*When a lens comes bundled with the camera there is usually small discount and you can mostly count on the fact that the bundled lens is as current as the camera itself,* although sometimes a newer model may supersede it.

Comment: Yes, it really is confusing.. Thanks for your reply! I'll place a new buy tomorrow!

Answer (score 2):

You might have a look at the question [What do all those cryptic number and letter codes in a lens name mean?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/496/what-do-all-those-cryptic-number-and-letter-codes-in-a-lens-name-mean) for some more information about what the different acronyms means.

I'm not too familiar with Nikon (Nikkor), but it does look like Nikon only have one 16-85 lens. And by buying a camera + lens as a package, you would normally get a discount. My guess is that this is the same lens.

Comment: Hmm, takk! Kjøper pakken fra Komplett da. :)

Answer (score 1):

I own the lens and there is only one version of this lens. So they should be the same lens.