# What does "R" mean in Fujifilm's XF Fujinon lens names?

Tags: lens, terminology, fujifilm

Fujifilm currently makes three lenses for their new [X-Pro1](http://www.fujifilm.com/products/digital_cameras/x/fujifilm_x_pro1/) mirrorless camera system:

- [Fujinon XF18mmF2 R](http://www.fujifilm.com/products/digital_cameras/x/fujinon_lens_xf18mmf2_r/)
- [Fujinon XF35mmF1.4 R](http://www.fujifilm.com/products/digital_cameras/x/fujinon_lens_xf35mmf14_r/)
- [Fujinon XF60mmF2.4 R Macro](http://www.fujifilm.com/products/digital_cameras/x/fujinon_lens_xf60mmf24_r_macro/)

"Fujinon" is Fujifilm's lens division. The "X" stands for "X-mount", where the letter *X* comes from "X is a letter which sounds cool" (in the catalog, they use the term *'X'treme*,with no apparent hint of Gen X irony). And "XF" is either all lenses for this mount, or at least the first series of such lenses.

Next, we have the focal length and aperture — straightforward enough. But then all three are suffixed with this "R". I can't find any indication of what this might stand for in the literature, nor can I find it on [older Fujinon lenses](http://www.pentax-manuals.com/fujica/lenses/bay_lenses.htm). So, what does it mean?

Comment: Related: [What do all those cryptic number and letter codes in a lens name mean?](//photo.stackexchange.com/a/85053)

Comment: Note that XF are Fuji's more expensive metal lenses, which come in either black and red label and XC are the cheaper plastic ones. Compare the XC 16-50mm f/3.5-5.6 and the XF 18-55 f/2.8-4 (black label) and XF 16-55 f/2.8 (red label). (I'm sure you know that by now, but it invalidates a statement in the question)

Comment: @Belle-Sophie Yeah, there were no XC lenses back when I asked this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> "R" stands for Ring and means the lens is equipped with an aperture ring.

(From Fujifilm's [FAQ](http://digital-cameras.support.fujifilm.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/19290/p/546).)

Comment: Oh, nice! They finally put this somewhere official. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In their [review of the XF 14mm lens, Digital Photography Review says](http://www.dpreview.com/lensreviews/fujifilm-xf-14-f2-8r)

> The 'R' in the lens name indicates that, like the other XF primes to date, the 14mm has a dedicated ring to control the aperture.

This means that the lens aperture can be either directly controlled by setting this ring (although in fact the connections on this modern lens mount are are all electronic even when using the manual ring), or left in auto mode by choosing `A`.

In a [comment thread](http://www.dpreview.com/news/2013/4/2/just-posted-our-fujifilm-fujinon-xf-14mm-f-2-8-r-lens-review), DPR's Andy Westlake adds:

> Fujifilm's launch presentation to us about this lens and the XF 18-55mm, given by senior members of the design team in Japan, unequivocally stated that 'R' stands for aperture ring.

Additionally, the newer [Fujifilm XF 27mm f/2.8](http://www.fujifilmusa.com/products/digital_cameras/x/fujinon_lens_xf27mmf28/) has no aperture ring — and no 'R'.

Comment: Right, this lens has the ability to be both auto and manual. The Ring pushes forward to become manual.

Comment: @cmason: that's for the _focus_ ring. I think the 14mm is the first XF lens to have the manual focus switch feature, but others have the `R` designation.

Comment: Also a bit off-topic but worth noting that even in manual focus mode, focus is electronically-driven; the ring has no direct connection.

Comment: @mattdm  - Fuji has updated their [roadmap](http://www.fujifilm.ca/press/news/display_news?newsID=166) with a XF 27mm F/2.8 which has an aperture ring but no R in its name.

Comment: @Itai And, presumably, no rounded aperture blades?

Comment: @Itai Hmm, actually, that new lens looks like a pancake design, and maybe _won't_ have an aperture ring? The press release doesn't say either way, and it's hard to tell from the fuzzy little picture.

Comment: @mattdm - Yes, it is a pancake design. There are two rings on it still because Fuji cameras do not have aperture controls. The only way it would not have an aperture ring or focus ring would be a fixed-focus fixed-aperture lens. I have not put up the larger image but [DPReview has](http://www.dpreview.com/previews/fujifilm-55-200-3p5-4p8/images/roadmap.jpg) where you can see both rings.

Comment: @Itai I'm going to hold off until we see the released lens (I think the dpreview image still counts as little and fuzzy, and may be a mockup in any case). That should answer the rounded aperture blades question too. It's possible that the lens lacks the ability to select aperture, allowing only P and Tv modes (weird, but possible!) or that a camera firmware update will allow some way to set the aperture from the camera controls.

Comment: @Itai I'm afraid it looks to be the other way: Fujifilm says that the released lens [has no aperture ring](http://www.fujifilm.com/news/n130625_02.html). You can see an updated picture here: [only one ring](http://www.fujifilmusa.com/products/digital_cameras/x/fujinon_lens_xf27mmf28/). )As I suggested in my previous comment, they've updated the firmware to allow control from the camera's wheel.) And the lens _does_ have rounded aperture blades.

Answer (score -1):

I saw this question and I was also curious and according to Fujirumors on facebook it stands for Rangefinder.

Comment: Seems as good a possiblity as any, but I wonder if _they_ are just guessing.

Comment: Very odd. I will has Fuji. I would have imagined something more along the line of *rear-focus* or *reduced flange distance*.