# What are the details of the lens that comes with the Fuji X-T20?

Tags: lens, fujifilm, kit-lens

I have been reading about the [Fuji X-T20 camera](http://www.fujifilm.com/products/digital_cameras/x/fujifilm_x_t20/) and have been trying to find out the Focal length range of base lens which comes with camera but cannot trace it in specifications.

Can someone guide me on where to look for those details?

I am very new to cameras so might be missing something obvious

Comment: See http://www.fujifilm.com/products/digital_cameras/x/fujifilm_x_t20/features/page_06.html for compatible lenses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The X-T20 is just a camera body and doesn't necessarily come with a lens at all. What you're probably thinking of is that interchangable lens cameras are often sold in a package with a "kit lens", but you would need to check the details of the package rather than just the camera.

Answer (score 1):

The X-T20 is often bundled with the  [Fujinon XF18-55mmF2.8-4 R LM OIS](http://www.fujifilm.com/products/digital_cameras/x/fujinon_lens_xf18_55mmf28_4_r_lm_ois/specifications/) lens whose main specifications are:
 - Focal length: 18 - 55mm (35mm format equivalent:27 - 84mm)
 - Variable Max. aperture: F2.8 - F4 / Min. aperture: F22 
 - **Aperture ring**
 - Optical stabilization
This is a high quality lens zoom which has been praised by the testers.

This lens should not be confused with the [FUJINON LENS XC16-50mmF3.5-5.6 OIS II](http://www.fujifilm.com/products/digital_cameras/x/fujinon_lens_xc16_50mmf35_56_ois_2/specifications/) which part of a lesser quality line of lens, and **without the aperture ring**

For the record, a third zoom [FUJINON LENS XF16-55mmF2.8 R LM WR](http://www.fujifilm.com/products/digital_cameras/x/fujinon_lens_xf16_55mmf28_r_lm_wr/specifications/) exists too.

Comment: Note that the aperture ring is indicated by the "R" in the lens name. See https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/22252/what-does-r-mean-in-fujifilms-xf-fujinon-lens-names