# Can I use a Fotodiox Nikon F Mount lens to Fujifilm X-series camera adapter with Nikon D-type lenses?

Tags: lens, nikon, lens-mount, lens-adapter

I would like to know if I can use this Fotodiox Adapter, [Nikon Nikkor F Mount G-Type D/SLR Lenses to Fujifilm X-series mirrorless cameras](https://fotodioxpro.com/products/nikg-fxrf-dlx), to adapt my old lenses to my Fujifilm XT-1 camera. My lenses are:

- AF NIKKOR 28 mm 1:2.8 D
- AF NIKKOR 28-70 mm 1:3.5-4.5 D

After reading the description, I'm not sure. Are these lenses D-type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your lenses are "D"-type Nikkor lenses. See the accepted answer to this question: [What is the difference between Nikkor D type and G type lenses?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/45814/11924)

> **D-Type NIKKOR Lenses** ... Many D-Type lenses have an aperture control ring and can be used on older Nikon SLR cameras that allow for manual control of the aperture, as well as on D-SLRs ...
>
> **G-Type NIKKOR Lenses** A G-type lens does not have an aperture control ring and are intended for use on Nikon D-SLRs that allow the lens aperture to be adjusted via the camera's command dial. ... **The lack of an aperture control ring is perhaps the easiest way that you can tell if a lens is a G-Type NIKKOR or not.**

See also the [Nikon-specific answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/76183/11924) to the question, [What do all those cryptic number and letter codes in a lens name mean?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/496/11924)

---

This Fotodiox adapter will work with any Nikon F-mount AI or AI-S (or later) lens to mount to your Pentax camera.

The adapter was designed to allow Nikon G lenses (those without aperture control rings, which are Nikon's latest mechanical aperture lenses) to be used, by providing the aperture control ring in the adapter. The adapter's aperture control ring moves a lever than pushes the mechanical aperture linkage in the Nikon lens in the same way that a Nikon camera body would control the lens's aperture.

The aperture control ring in the Fotodiox adapter is superfluous / redundant for your needs, but its presence won't cause any harm or limit the lens's function.

When using this adapter with your Fuji body and your Nikon D lenses, you should leave the Fotodiox adapter's aperture set to the smallest aperture setting, and use the lens's aperture ring to control your exposure.

Comment: @Antonio Because this is SE, and not a messageboard, consider [accepting](http://photo.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), or (when you get the rep) [upvoting](http://photo.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) an answer instead of a thanks comment. Please, take [the tour](http://photo.stackexchange.com/tour) if you plan to stick around.