# What does f/4.5-5.6G stand for on a Nikon Lens?

Tags: lens, nikon

Can you please explain me what is 4.5 - 5.6G in a lense description.And how it is different from other generation of like 3.5G or 6.5.

"Nikon AF-S DX NIKKOR 55 - 300 mm f/4.5-5.6G ED VR Lens"

Comment: Some of it is covered here:  http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/496/what-do-all-those-cryptic-number-and-letter-codes-in-a-lens-name-mean

Comment: I'd say it's *all* covered there, with the possible exception of variable aperture zooms. That can be easily fixed with an edit though...

Answer (score 2):

That simply refers to the Maximum Aperture of the lens.

The terms in that lens name are as follows:

- AF-S - Auto Focus - Silent
- DX - Designed for Nikon crop sensor bodies
- 55-300mm - Focal length range of the lens
- f/4.5-5.6 - Maximum aperture of the lens at min and max focal lengths
- G - No manual aperture control on the lens, aperture must be controlled by the camera body
- ED - Extra-Low Dispersion glass
- VR - Vibration Reduction - basically reduces the effect of camera shake.

So generally none of that refers to the Generation of the lens, just the features and specifications of the lens. There may be a "II" on the end of some lens names indicating that it is the 2nd version of that lens.

There are other acronyms you will see from time to time, there is a good reference on the Nikon site: https://support.nikonusa.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/9919/~/glossary-of-nikkor-lens-terms

Comment: The "II" designation is applied to successive versions of the same lens where the alphabet soup and basic specs are otherwise the same.  The 70-200 f/2.8 and 18-200 f/3.5-5.6 are examples of where they did this; the three versions of the 24-120 that have been released over the last 20 years are examples of where they didn't.

Answer (score 0):

4.5-5.6 mean maximum aperture of the lens. It is variable so as you zoom it change, 4.5 at 55mm and 5.6 at 300mm.

G mean aperture is managed from the camera. You do not have aperture ring on the lens