# Can Tamron 16-300mm Macro Lens fit to Canon EOS 600D?

Tags: lens, canon, lens-mount, tamron

I use Canon EOS 600D and I want a lens with a larger range. I found out Tamron 16-300 f/3.5-6.3 Di II VC PZD Macro Lens, I added it into my wishlist.
I did some research on it and I'm scared that it couldn't fit to my Canon EOS 600D. 
I'm still a beginner... I'm confused with EF, EF-S and APS-C/DX. Can someone please explain it to me?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Just make sure that you buy the Canon mount version for this lens, as third party lens makers generally also make versions with mounts for Nikon and other camera brands.

Answer (score 0):

The **EF** or **EF-s** version of this lens will work on your camera, or any ASP-C Canon EOS DSLR, or the EOS M, with a separate adapter (the EF-s to EF-m adapter). The lens will be able to be attached to other Canon DSLRs (i.e. 1D, 5D, or 6D) but extreme vignetting (i.e. very dark corners of the image, possible extending a significant distance into the image) will occur due to a reduced image circle size.

For information on the letters please see [this question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/496/10405)

Comment: @MichaelClark The lens will fit the EOS M body with an adapter.

Comment: @MichaelClark It is quite obvious that "the lens" I am referring to is the one in the original question.

Comment: Not to mention that *any* Tamron lenses made for Canon EF mount will attach to *any* EOS DSLR. Tamron Di II lenses will only throw an image circle large enough to cover an APS-C sensor, but they will attach and function on a FF Canon DSLR with severe vignetting.

Comment: @MichaelClark To say that the lens works on all canon DSLRs is misleading, because, as you say, an extreme vignette will occur, ruining any photo for which this is not intended. Also what other lens could I be talking about? A small amount of research or knowledge or even pattern matching would indicate that the EOS M, 1D, 5D and 6D are bodies and not lenses.

Comment: The grammar of your original answer said those three full framed bodies would fit the EOS-M body via adapter. Thank you for revising the answer!

Comment: @MichaelClark The grammar did not say that. "1D, 5D, or 6D" cannot be referred to as the singular "it", therefore the general term "it" must refer to something else, i.e. either the "EOS M" or the original object that was being discussed, the lens.