# How to differentiate between a VR and VR II Nikkor lenses (e.g., 55-200 VR and 55-200 VRII)?

Tags: lens, nikon

I want to know how can I differentiate between VR and VRII lenses.
Nikkor has been providing a lens of same focal lengths 55-200 with VR and VRII.

Below is the VR II product pic [from Nikon's website](http://m.nikonusa.com/en/Nikon-Products/Product/Camera-Lenses/AF-S-DX-NIKKOR-55-200mm-f%252F4-5.6G-ED-VR-II.html). Nowhere on the lens can I see an indication that this is the VR II.

[image: VR II lenses pic which just says VR]

Comment: footnote: the **II** denotes the version of the lens's design, not the version of VR.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the side, VR II lens has "II" in the lower line, after max aperture values and [letter G](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/496/4390/what-do-all-those-cryptic-number-and-letter-codes-in-a-lens-name-mean) - AF-S Nikkor 55-200mm 1:4-5.6G**II** ED. The letters "VR II" can also be read around front element - 55-200mm 1:4-5.6G ED VR II:

[image: 55-200 VR II front element]

The earlier version has the side marking missing the *II* and no text around front element at all. Also, **VR** is a separate red marking rather than part of upper golden text row on side:

[55-200 VR http://images.forum-auto.com/mesimages/368591/nikon-55-200-vr.jpg](http://images.forum-auto.com/mesimages/368591/nikon-55-200-vr.jpg)

Some early (prototype?) copies will even have the side text "Nikon DX SWM VR ED IF ∞-1.1m/3.61ft Ø 52" in *white*, not golden letters. No red VR marking on those:

[image: 55-200 VR with white text]
<sub>(source: [cashconverters.com.au](https://webshop.cashconverters.com.au/thumbnail/850x520/1572892-nikon-nikkor-55-200-lens-1.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid the answer referencing the meaning of the roman numeral two is incorrect.
According to Nikon; "The Roman numeral you see in the printed name and on the lens barrel means the second generation of that particular lens."
https://www.nikonusa.com/en/learn-and-explore/a/tips-and-techniques/how-to-read-your-nikkor-lens-barrel.html

I suppose the good news is knowing what the roman numeral means, the bad news is that there is apparently no indication on the lens as to it having first or second generation VR technology.