# Can I use a Sigma 17-55 2.8 lens on a Canon 6D?

Tags: canon, lens-mount

Will the Sigma 17-55mm 2.8 lens fit my full-frame Canon 6D? I'm looking to purchase a zoom lens but don't know which direction to go, as I'm new to full frame.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do all those cryptic number and letter codes in a lens name mean?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/496/what-do-all-those-cryptic-number-and-letter-codes-in-a-lens-name-mean)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Will the sigma 17-55mm 2.8 lense fit my full frame canon 6d ?

The lens that I think you're talking about is the [Sigma 17-50mm f/2.8 EX DC (OS) HSM](http://www.sigmaphoto.com/lenses/standard-lenses/17-50mm-f28-ex-dc-os-hsm). Although any lens with an EF mount will fit your 6D, the "DC" designation means that the lens is designed for APS-C sensors rather than full frame, so the image won't cover the entire sensor. If you're looking at Sigma lenses, you should pick one with the "DG" designation, which tells you that it's designed for full frame sensors.