# How to get autofocus to work with D5100 and AF-P DX Nikkor

Tags: lens, nikon, nikon-d5100, af-p

I just bought Nikon 18 - 55 mm f/3.5 - 5.6G VR AF-P DX Nikkor from [Amazon UK](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Nikon-18-5-6G-Nikkor-Camera/dp/B01AI8H58I/ref=cm_cd_al_qh_dp_t).

When I connected it to my Nikon D5100, the autofocus didn't work. There was nothing about this from the original seller's website.

Is there anything I can do short of returning?

Answer (score 6):

No, there is nothing you can do. Nikon's AF-P lenses do not work with the D5100. At the time of release of the first AF-P lenses (the 18–55mm, both with and without VR), the only cameras that supported AF-P lenses were D5300 and D5500, and a firmware update was made available to the D3300 so it would support AF-P lenses as well.

See this article at Nikonrumors.com: [The new AF-P Nikkor 18–55mm f/3.5–5.6G DX lenses works only with three Nikon DSLR cameras](https://nikonrumors.com/2016/04/04/the-new-af-p-nikkor-18-55mm-f3-5-5-6g-dx-lenses-works-only-with-three-nikon-dslr-cameras.aspx/)
There has been no firmware update for the D5100 to support this lens.

---

Nikon's sites for the AF-P DX NIKKOR 18–55mm f/3.5–5.6G (both [with](http://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/lens/zoom/normalzoom/af-p_dx_18-55mmf_35-56g_vr/index.htm) and [without](http://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/lens/zoom/normalzoom/af-p_dx_18-55mmf_35-56g/index.htm) VR), and the AF-P DX NIKKOR 70–300mm f/4.5–6.3G ED (also both [with](http://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/lens/zoom/telephotozoom/af-p_dx_70-300mmf_45-63g_ed_vr/index.htm) and [without](http://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/lens/zoom/telephotozoom/af-p_dx_70-300mmf_45-63g_ed/index.htm) VR) make the following statements with respect to AF-P and autofocus with these lenses:

> * Because AF-P lenses incorporate a stepping motor, the number of compatible cameras is limited. Even for compatible cameras, firmware update may be required.
>
> * Because focus mode (AF/MF) is set using the camera menus, the number of compatible cameras is limited.

Note that these statements are not present on their page for the [AF-P DX NIKKOR 10–20mm f/4.5–5.6G VR](http://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/lens/zoom/widezoom/af-p_dx_10-20mmf45-56g_vr/index.htm) lens.

In the User Manuals for the [AF-P 18–55mm](http://download.nikonimglib.com/archive2/h1tja00GyzmR02WAbmT36B9sIH87/AFP18-55_3.5-5.6GVR_NT(7C_DL)02.pdf) and [AF-P 70–300mm](http://download.nikonimglib.com/archive2/bHl0g004L71T02K6GxZ57Mppen89/AFP70-300_4.5-6.3GEDVR_NT(7C_DL)02.pdf) lenses, Nikon states:

> This lens does not support D4-series, D3-series, D2-series, D1-series, D800- series, D700, D610, D600, D300-series, D200, D100, D90, D80, D70-series, D60, D50, D40-series, D7000, D5100, D5000, D3200, D3100 or D3000 digital SLR cameras or film SLR cameras. When using it with a D5500, D5300, or D3300, be sure the camera firmware has been updated to the latest version.

Ok... it's easier to state what bodies the lenses *do* support. Citing Thom Hogan's article at [dslrbodies.com regarding the AF-P 70–300mm lenses](http://www.dslrbodies.com/lenses/nikon-lens-reviews/nikkor-zoom-lens-reviews/nikon-70-300mm-f45-63-af-p.html),

> So here’s my conclusion:
>
> - D3400/D5500 users: this is the basic telephoto zoom to buy, no questions asked
> - D500, D3300, D5200, D5300 users: make sure you have the current firmware; probably the basic telephoto lens to buy
> - D7100, D7200 users: note that you can’t set VR to off; if that’s okay with you, consider the lens
> - All other older DX users: **do not buy this lens**

Comment: But I thought every F-mount lens since 1950-something works on every f-mount camera?

Comment: @MichaelClark - works for a given value of 'work' ;) Some don't fit, some will break the mirror; usually loss of AF or meter is the issue. I have spent a lot of time staring at Ken Rockwell's list of which suits which over the past year, every time I'm thinking about a new lens - http://www.kenrockwell.com/nikon/compatibility-lens.htm [Relevant table is about half-way down]

Comment: @scottbb There should be a separate menu option for autofocus on a camera that supports this lens. It seems that VR defaults to on and AF to off if the lens is attached to an unsupported body though.

Comment: Even the local camera shop was surprised by this when I told him. Nikon just lost a few points on me this week. Maybe Cannon is better long term ?

Comment: I mean how hard is it for them to release an update to the D5100?

Comment: @SuperUberDuper Canon made the hard decision way back in 1987 to make a break from the mechanical past and embrace the electronic future. Although they were roundly criticized at the time for 'abandoning' their existing customer base, once the technical advantages of their decision became apparent, it has proven to be the right one, at least for them. They are the world's leading seller of interchangeable lens cameras today largely due to that decision three decades ago. Other manufacturers dragged their feet and tried to make the future compatible with the past. They are still paying for it.

Comment: thx, But this is post about Nikon

Comment: @SuperUberDuper but you said just 2 comments previous to Michael's, "Maybe Canon is better long term?" Michael is giving some background into the history of choices made by Nikon and Canon.

Comment: whoops, sorry I forgot about that