# Will Nikon AF-S "G" lenses autofocus on D3xxx bodies?

Tags: lens, nikon, autofocus, video, af-s

When I checked the site of Nikon for D3300 camera, I found following description

> Autofocus is available with AF-S and AF-I lenses; Autofocus is not
>   available with other type G and D lenses, AF lenses (IX NIKKOR and
>   lenses for the F3AF are not supported) and AI-P lenses; Non-CPU lenses
>   can be used in mode M but the camera exposure meter will not function
>   The electronic rangefinder can be used with lenses that have a maximum
>   aperture of f/5.6 or faster

[Source](http://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/dslr/d3300/spec.htm)

I am confused with what it means. Does it mean that auto-focus is not supported for following version (for example)

- Nikon 18-200mm F/3.5-5.6**G** IF-ED AF-S VR II DX

because it has "G" mentioned in aperture? I am confused because it says that it is auto focus.

I usually choose focal point to focus on subject while taking pictures but I use auto while shooting videos. As now I am planning to shoot more videos so do I have to worry about these properties?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Nikon 18-200mm F/3.5-5.6G IF-ED **AF-S** VR II DX lens will autofocus on your D3300.

The important statement is: "**Autofocus is available with AF-S** and AF-I lenses".

The secondary statement, "Autofocus is not available with **other** type G and D lenses," means that G- and D-type lenses that *are not* AF-S or AF-I won't autofocus on your D3300.

The "G" in Nikon lens designations means there is no manual aperture control ring for the user to set the aperture on the lens; the camera body must perform the aperture control.

See also the [Nikon answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/76183/11924) to [What do all those cryptic number and letter codes in a lens name mean?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/496/what-do-all-those-cryptic-number-and-letter-codes-in-a-lens-name-mean/76183#76183)

Comment: Would it be true to say that most type G lenses are also AF-S lenses? It is true that ALL G type lenses are also D type lenses (but far from true that all D type lenses are also G type lenses).

Comment: @MichaelClark I think it's fair to say most G lenses are AF-S. The only other G lenses I can think of are AF-P, which are compatible with the D3300 after a firmware update on the body. According to the [Nikon answer to "cryptic number and letter codes..."](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/76183/11924), all AF-S, AI-S, and G lenses are D-type ("distance" reporting)

Comment: @Scottbb One question though. Is it important to have auto focus? I mean AF-S lens are costly. If I take only AF lens will I face any issue? (ex: when I enable face tracking in movie mode)

Comment: Can't really answer that question for you. How important is autofocus _to you_? As you mention, face tracking won't keep a subject in focus without af.