# Fixed Focal Length Lens for DX camera

Tags: dslr, dx

I want to get a good Fixed Focal Length Lens with wide aperture for my Nikon D5300 which is a DX Camera and while searching for lens in India there were only 4 lens for DX compared to the 44 lens for FX body. Out of the 4 one was a Fisheye Lens so I have three choices. Should I get the DX model or choose from the FX lens. The focal length that I want is only available in the FX lens
The Availabe Lens are:

1. 35mm f/1.8
2. 85mm f/3.5
3. 40mm f/2.8

I wanted to get the AF-S 50mm f/1.8 or 50mm f/1.4 both of which are FX lenes. I am a little particular about the 50mm - 55mm  as I feel that is the best focal length for the type of photos that I usually take. I am also open to other lens with lower focal length as I can always crop in post.

What should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're absolutely fine putting an FX lens on a DX body - it's the other way round that has issues with vignetting at the corners. If you ever move up to a full-frame body, you can take an FX lens with you.

Watch out for older lenses that need a motor in the camera to enable auto-focus. Newer lower-end cameras don't have a built-in motor & need the lens to have it built-in.

If you want a fast 50mm you can use the AF-S 1.8G or AF-S 1.4G but **not** the older AF 1.4 or 1.8D versions, you would lose auto-focus.
I have the AF-S Nikkor 50mm f/1.4G for my D5500 & it's just fabulous.

There is a confusing array of code letters on Nikon lenses, so if you are in doubt, check [this answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/76183/15871) to [What do all those cryptic number and letter codes in a lens name mean?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/496/15871) or [Ken Rockwell's Compatibility List](http://www.kenrockwell.com/nikon/compatibility-lens.htm)

Answer (score 1):

If you want a 50mm lens, you should get the 50mm (or look for third party options).

But I believe what you actually want, is a **50mm Full-Frame equivalent** lens. In this case, get the **35mm**. This lens provides roughly the same field of view on your DX boody as a 50mm lens on  FX Body

---

Edit after question update:

OP specified, that he/she actually wants a 50mm lens. So [the answer by @Tetsujin](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/93189/61302) probably correct here.

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. I have only used crop-frame in recent years & I actually 'think' in crop-frame when choosing a focal length. But, it's a valid point, for sure.

Comment: I don't want to try third party options as even Sigma has only 12 service centers in India and third party lens are also difficult to sell in case i want to upgrade to a FX camera in the future

Comment: @Tetsujin OP just specified the question, so your answer is probably the best. Have my upvote ;-)