# Can these lens be used on a Nikon D300?

Tags: lens, nikon

I have these old lens, that I mounted on a Nikon F601m, now broken:

- Nikon AF Nikkor 50mm 1:1.8
- Nikon AF Nikkor 28mm 1:2.8
- Sigma UC Zoom 70-210mm 1:4-5.6

Now I am thinking of buying a used Nikon D300, but I ask if I can still use my old lens. Thank you.

Comment: Related - https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/496/what-do-all-those-cryptic-number-and-letter-codes-in-a-lens-name-mean & http://www.kenrockwell.com/nikon/compatibility-lens.htm

Comment: Also: https://www.nikonians.org/reviews/nikon-slr-camera-and-lens-compatibility

Comment: Also: [This list from Nikon of lens types and which specific camera models are fully or partially compatible with each type.](https://www.nikonusa.com/Images/Learn-Explore/Photography-Techniques/2011/Which-Nikkor-is-Right-for-You/Media/NIKKOR-lens-compatibility-chart.pdf)