# What camera fits this a Osawa MC 1:4.5 f=80~205mm lens?

Tags: lens, lens-mount, camera, equipment-identification

I found a lens and I was wondering what camera fits it? Does it fit a canon 1300? & also how can I tell if it works or not? (If that’s possible) (As I found it on the ground). I don’t have a camera at the moment to check if it works or not. Also what type of lens is it?

I can’t take a picture because it’s limited to 2mib, but it says “ Osawa MC 1:4.5 f=80~205mm 52ø No. 383979. ”

Comment: 2MB is more than enough for a picture of a lens!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do all those cryptic number and letter codes in a lens name mean?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/496/what-do-all-those-cryptic-number-and-letter-codes-in-a-lens-name-mean)

Comment: I’m taking the picture with my phone and it says that the image is too big and my phone is iphone5 so idk & thank you for your answer!

Comment: Without a picture of the lens's mount, we cannot tell you what the mount is. Please save or export a lower-resolution version of the image on your phone, and upload it to your edited question. Thank you! =)

Comment: The type of lens is shown by the 80 - 205mm marking. The lens has a focal distance of 80mm to 205mm. It could be useful for macro shots, or zoomed in shots, but Osawa is on the whole a fairly cheap brand, so chances are the optics and build quality are not brilliant. I have a very similar Hanimex lens which is useful on occasion, but not mind-blowing. I would not recommend buying a camera specifically to use this lens, but if you get a body in the future, it would be worth trying it out. It's not likely to lose or gain value if you decide to sell it down the line.

Comment: @ValentinaOliverio Use an app to scale the image down so it's not saved as full size.

Answer (score 2):

That lens was made in many different mounts. You can search eBay to see if you can match up the lens with a particular mount.

If it is a Nikon mount(except non AI) or Pentax K mount, you will be able to use it on a current Nikon or Pentax DSLR camera. If it is one of the other manual focus mounts from the film camera era, you will need an adapter to fit a modern DSLR. Some mounts can be easily adapted to Modern cameras, and some can’t. Mirrorless cameras are designed to have the lens mounted close to the image sensor, and this makes it easier to use old film era lenses with adapters.

The lens sells for about $25 on eBay and is probably not worth the effort as results will be disappointing.

Here are a few examples of this lens in different mounts taken from from eBay listings.

Canon FD mount
[image]

Pentax screw mount
[image]

Nikon mount
[image]

Comment: "If it is one of the other mounts from the film camera era, you will probably need an adapter to fit a modern DSLR." Not really. If it's Minolta MC/MD or Canon FD, it'll probably need an adapter. If it's Minolta A, Pentax K, or Canon EF (all of which were used in film cameras for decades) they'll mount to DSLRs without a problem. Of the AF film mounts, Nikon's is probably the one that requires the *most* care to ensure compatibility.

Comment: There have been plenty of non-AF lenses made for AF mounts...

Comment: Nikon (except non AI) and Pentax K are the only manual focus era lenses that will fit on current respective DSLRs without an adapter. All the other mounts were redesigned to accomdate Auto Focus. The Osawa lens being discussed is from the manual focus era and will not fit Minolta A, or Canon EF mounts unless some sort of an adapter is used. If the adapter needs optical correction to insure infinity focus, the image quality will suffer. The image quality of this Osawa lens is not great to start with so it would be a waste of time and effort in my opinion.

Answer (score -4):

It depends whether your lens is the Macro (http://allphotolenses.com/lenses/item/c_898.html) or non-Macro version (http://allphotolenses.com/lenses/item/c_3309.html).

Assuming its the non-Macro version, your lens would fit any M42 lens mount cameras, such has a number of Praktica's, Fujica's, the Olympus FTL, Pentax, Yashica, Pentax cameras and others. With the use of an adapter you may even fit it in almost every modern lens mount, including the Canon EF, Nikon F, Olympus FourThirds, Pentax K-mount, Minolta/Sony A-mount and others.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M42_lens_mount

Comment: those pages at allphotolenses.com are not canonical nor exhaustive. This lens was made for several mounts, including (but not limited to) M42. Without a photo of the mount end of the OP's lens, there's no way to know which mount the lens is for.