# Can Nikon SLR lenses be used on Fujifilm X series cameras?

Tags: nikon, lens-mount, lens-adapter, fujifilm

I want to buy a FujiFilm X-series camera, and wonder if I will be able to use my Nikon (Nikkor) lens with it.

Answer (score 3):

**Nikon F-mount lenses can be adapted to FujiFilm X-mount.** They can be divided into three categories.

1. Lenses with aperture ring. These can be used with any NF-FX adapter.
2. Lenses without aperture ring, but with mechanical aperture linkage. (G) The aperture on these lenses can be controlled with aperture control rings on appropriately designed adapters.
3. Lenses without aperture ring, and electronically controlled aperture. (E) These lenses can be used only wide open.

Also, be aware that when using an adapter, **you will need to focus the lenses manually**. There are currently no "smart" adapters that support autofocus for Nikon lenses, though there are rumored to be some in development.

When selecting an adapter, consider the following:

- Adapters with aluminum bodies and stainless steel or brass mounts can be expected to work well. Most adapters that are labeled with *some* brand are constructed this way. Most of the adapters I use are made by Fotasy. Other brands I've used include Fotodiox and Dollice. I've had no problems with them.
- Adapters with brushed metal (Kipon) will abrade the mount on your lens, and I suggest avoiding them.
- Generic, unbranded adapters from China *may* be made entirely of aluminum that will fall apart.

**See also:**

- [Can I use lens brand X on interchangeable lens camera brand Y?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/62000/75526)
- [What do all those cryptic number and letter codes in a lens name mean?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/76183/75526)