# Are there two different versions of the Nikon 24-120mm f/4G lens?

Tags: lens, nikon

I've recently been thinking about investing in the Nikon AF-S NIKKOR 24-120mm f/4G ED VR Lens for landscape photography. I've been looking around to see what a used one is going for, only to find that there may be **two different versions**. Can anybody confirm?

[https://www.amazon.com/Nikon-Nikkor-24-120mm-ED-IF-Bundle/dp/B006FR1B96/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B006FR1B96)

[https://www.amazon.com/Nikon-0-945-4-724-NIKKOR-Lente-Digital/dp/B003ZSHNEK/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B003ZSHNEK)

My second question is, what is the difference? All these acronyms make the buying process a little frustrating.

Comment: Re ID codes - https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/496/what-do-all-those-cryptic-number-and-letter-codes-in-a-lens-name-mean but those 2 lenses look the same to me, afaik, there's only one f/4 24-120, the older one is f/3.5-4.5 [which is the one I had … & hated ;)

Comment: There is only one version of the 24-120mm f/4. I think the one at your first link is a gray-market one, because the seller, 6 Ave, mostly sells gray-market goods. If it were an authorized Nikon USA unit, they could not set the price so low because Nikon USA wouldn't allow it. I note that the listing claims to include the 1+5-year warranty, but that may be an oversight.

Comment: The gray market also claims to be VR II, which Nikon does not have a product with that moniker

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the first link (the $528.75 lens) may be a **GREY MARKET** lens and thus may not be subjected to the full warranty that **Nikon** provides. They are usually sold by 3rd-party retailers on sites such as Adorama, B&H, and Amazon. The seller on Amazon for this particular lens is  **6ave, not Amazon**. The second lens, costly a fair bit more, is **sold by Amazon**, (not a 3rd party reseller) and have included **specification sheets** and **user manual** directly linked to the  **Nikon** corporation themselves.

Answer (score 0):

The naming in the headline of the first link is incorrect as Nikon only every released a single version of the 24-120 with a constant F/4 aperture.

The fact that they made up a new name to make the lens seem newer is a red flag and so I would recommend avoiding purchasing from such a vendor.