# Identifying full frame lens

Tags: lens, nikon

I have a D7100 with three lens, a Nikon SWM VR ED IF 077, a Nikon SWM 058 and a Sigma DC 072. I am considering moving to a full frame Nikon and trying to identity if all or any of my lens are considered full frame ?.  Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Those aren't the lens models or specs.

Comment: The numbers you have quoted only relate to the diameter of the lens. The letters you have quoted refer to lens features/characteristics. But nothing you've given here actually identifies a lens. You can find a full list of current Nikon DSLR lenses [here](https://www.nikon.co.uk/en_GB/product/nikkor-lenses). Notice that for every lens, the focal length (or focal length range) and the aperture are given. That's essential for identifying a lens. But provide the full name if you can.

Comment: [What do all those cryptic number and letter codes in a lens name mean?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/496/what-do-all-those-cryptic-number-and-letter-codes-in-a-lens-name-mean)

Comment: Voting to reopen so that it can be properly closed as a duplicate of [What do all those cryptic number and letter codes in a lens name mean?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/496/15871), which seems to me to be much more helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You need to turn the lens round ;)

SWM Ø58 is Silent Wave Motor, 58mm filter thread size. (some of these reverse descriptions are far more complex - eg DX SWM VR ED IF Aspherical… etc etc.) In either case the lens's full 'title' is on the other face.

In this case, SWM Ø58…

[image]

…is revealed as an AF-S NIKKOR 50mm 1:1.4G

[image]

That doesn't necessarily mean yours is the same, only that the filter size is the same.

However, the reverse description seems to always include DX if it's actually a DX lens, so if none of your Nikon lenses say DX, then they're good for a full frame Nikon. I don't own any Sigma lenses so I'm not certain if their descriptions follow the same pattern.

Comment: For Sigma, DC lenses are APs-C only and DG lenses are full frame.

Comment: Thanks very much for the responses I am still not quite sure what indicates the model name of the lens. My big lens has a gold plate on the lens that says Nikon ED followed by AF-s VR-NIKKOR 70-200mm 1:2.8G. So as there is no DX designation is that the model name and is that lens considered a full frame lens. Thanks again for your help. Its awesome

Comment: Correct, no DX designation means it's FX (full-frame).

Comment: My prime lens is a NIKON AF-S Nikkor 50mm 1:1.4G  so can I assume this is also a full frame lens ?