# What are some abbreviations used in the photography industry?

Tags: terminology

For example, **DCIM** is short for  Digital Camera Images.

When typing the name of something into a search engine  it is useful for the computer to know that the strings of text `DCIM` and `DIGITAL CAMERA IMAGES` both represent the same thing.

What other examples are there of standard initialisms, acronyms, or abbreviations used in the photography industry?

Comment: "List of things" type questions don't work well on Stack Exchange.

Comment: Lenses don't account for all the acronyms, but they are most of them. Closed as a dupe of the lens abbr question, with CW answer also pointing to WP's list of abbreviations.

Answer (score 0):

- For lenses only, see: [What do all those cryptic number and letter codes in a lens name mean?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/496/what-do-all-those-cryptic-number-and-letter-codes-in-a-lens-name-mean)
- For photography (both brand-specific, and non-brand) in general, see Wikipedia's [List of abbreviations in photography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_abbreviations_in_photography).